# Auto-Event Tracking In Google Tag Manager Click Events/Listerner not firing on Magento 2 website

Tags: events, magento2, google-tag-manager

Im trying to build a trigger on a Click Element -> Matches CSS selector -> ....
The problem is I dont see any Click Events in the summary tab when I click arround.  The Click variables are enabled in GTM menu. There is a Click All Elements trigger published. Is there an easy fix for making clicks available so I can use the clicks events?

[image: GTM Summary]
[image: Click Element]

Answer (score 0):

Create a click trigger in the trigger menu. It can be blank and fire on all clicks.

Comment: Hi, I Allready did this, I published a trigger on all pages(All- Elements - All Clicks. The issue is not solved. Any other suggestions? No click events are in the summary.

Comment: The issue was due to multiple tracking codes on the website. Hope this helps someone else!